# Engine high temperature

Tags: overheating

I was driving my car and just got notification of engine high temperature. I checked water and found thick brownish liquid in the  water bottle. My mechanic checked it and told me that i need oil cooler,fan switch,antifreezer and radiator flush. Never said anything about head gasket

Answer (score 0):

Your mechanic may very well be right.  I have a car with an oil cooler and the problem you describe is quite common, requiring only an oil cooler gasket replacement.